# Support for MySQL or AWS RDS for Janusgraph

Tags: mysql, graph, rds, janusgraph

Im planning to move away from cassandra/hbase as a storage backend for janusgraph and before even starting my work on MySql/RDS integration.

I wanted to know "**Is there a MySQL/AWS RDS storage support for JanusGraph or anyone working on that  ??**"